Need strftime() output in the buffer
The command
:echo strftime("%F")

works, but the result stays on the command line.
I tried put command to no avail:
:put =strftime("%F")

How do I get the answer in the buffer?

Welcome to [vi.se]!

not strftime, but another way to put date into the buffer :r !date -Idate if you are in posix environment.

In short, you need to use single quotes instead of double quotes for this command:
:put =strftime('%F')

The double quote character indicates the start of a comment in Ex (Vim command-line mode), see :help :quote for details.
Some commands are special in that they disable comments and make the " character behave as you'd expect (see the list of commands in the documentation.) It turns out :echo is one of them, which makes your first example work, but :put is not, so it doesn't trigger the behavior that prevents the string from being interpreted as a comment.
Using single quotes will work.

Thanks for this excellent answer. I have no idea how you worked it out. The help section in strftime makes no mention of single quotes. They could have done a better job than giving examples with double quotes and echo.

Mainly having had experience with this exact same issue in the past, in particular the :put command is the one that trips me the most often with this, specifically because it's a handy way to access the expression register!

@user167612 double quotes are not a strftime() issue. I wouldn't expect documentation to go out of its way to cover it. The appropriate place is :help :quote and that's where you'll find that some commands interpret double quotes as a comment while some don't. Feel free to improve an open source project, though.

@Friedrich I do agree with OP user167612 that this is hard to figure out, the error message you get (E116: Invalid arguments for function strftime) is not very helpful either, even :help E116 only says "function call" and doesn't really give any hints. Like I said, experience led me to the issue quickly, but it can be tricky for someone new to vimscript.

:put has a few limitations -- see filbranden's answer. When I need expressions that are too complex for it, I use of these two workarounds:

either I store what I wish to display into a variable and conclude with :put
:let myvariable = strftime("%F")
:put=myvariable


or, I use append() instead.
:call append('.', strftime("%F"))



But we could also go into insert mode, and use :i_CTRL-R: o^R=strftime("%F")^M^[. Here with o + <esc> I emulate :put behaviour, but just <c-r>=expression<cr> can be done at any time in insert mode.

Sounds interesting. Perhaps you could provide an example for both cases. Thanks

Clever use of append() and good tip with insert mode. Thanks you.

Another way to get an expression's return value into the buffer is to use a map expression.
The following will insert today's date when pressing F2 in Insert mode:
:inoremap <expr> <F2> strftime('%F')

The <expr> will cause the mapping's right hand side to be evaluated as an expression.
See :help map-<expr> for the details.
(By the way, the mapping would also work with "%F", i.e. with double quotes. I try to avoid them like the plague for the reason given in filbranden's excellent answer.)
To also make the mapping available from Normal and Visual modes, you can define two more (recursive) mappings like this:
:nmap <F2> a<F2><Esc>
:vmap <F2> s<F2><Esc>

A variation on this approach (if you prefer not to use a function key) is to use an abbreviation expression like this:
:iabbrev <expr> @date@ strftime('%F')

This way, you can type "@date@" and Vim will automatically replace it with today's date.

Not seen this way of using abbreviations. Very clever, thank you.
